# draggable needs to scale on revert

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an object change its size on mousedown and want it to return to full size if incorrect. I can't figure out how to make it change it's size after it's been dragged.

I've tried adding commands in revert, mouseup, another function that gets called... I'm stumped. I added alerts in all of these areas and they work. It just ignores height() and width().

```
function dragAndDrop(draggedItem,dropZone,scaleHeight,scaleWidth)
{
var bool = 0;
var draggedItem = $(draggedItem);
var dragFromLeft = draggedItem.offset().left;
var dragFromTop = draggedItem.offset().top;
var dropZone = $(dropZone);
var currentMousePos = { x: 0, y: 0};

draggedItem.draggable //Make item draggable
({
    opacity:1, 
    revert:function()//'invalid'
    {
        $(".strobeRed").fadeTo(100, .50).fadeTo(100, 0);
        $(this).offset({top: dragFromTop, left: dragFromLeft}).height(500);
    }
})

draggedItem.mousedown(function(event){
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX - (scaleWidth/2);  
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY - (scaleHeight/2);
    $(this).height(scaleHeight);
    $(this).width(scaleWidth);
    $(this).offset({top: currentMousePos.y, left: currentMousePos.x});
});

dropZone.droppable //Make item droppable
({
    accept:draggedItem,
    drop: function(event, ui)
    {
        //$( ui.draggable ).fadeOut(),
        $( this ).droppable( "option", "disabled", true ).css("background-color", "green"), //$(this) = $(event.target)
        $( this ).draggable( "option", "disabled", true )

    },
    tolerance: "touch"
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a jquery version mismatch. We are stuck using edge 1x which has jquery 1.7.1. By upgrading to 2.2.0, the problem was solved. Thanks @ryan0319 for working through this with me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert

You are missing the required return of `true` on the revert function. AS per the documentation:

`Function: A function to determine whether the element should revert to its start position. The function must return true to revert the element.`

Edit: To clarify

```
revert:function() {
    $(".strobeRed").fadeTo(100, .50).fadeTo(100, 0);
    $(this).offset({top: dragFromTop, left: dragFromLeft}).height(500);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I looked at this earlier, if I use true, can I still trigger a function?

Comment: Return true at the end of the function you have

Comment: When I did that, the size still doesn't change and it reintroduces the item walking around upon revert.

Comment: My project is in edge animate  so I can't put it in but I did make something that is similar. Odd thing is, it works great in code pen. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPoeeq

Comment: Yes it does! I guess you'll have to compare the two and tweak you code :/